# python wordpress xmlrpc. How to pass variable to wp.call

Tags: python, wordpress, xml-rpc, xmlrpclib

its all about wordpress_xmlrpc for python
lets start with code:

wp1 = Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username1', 'pass1')
wp2 = Client('http://example.com/xmlrpc.php', 'username2', 'pass2')

this works fine when I try to add new comment:
komment_id = wp1.call(NewComment(post_id, komment))
komment_id = wp2.call(NewComment(post_id, komment))

however I would like to do it randomly, so
Im looking for solution to change X to number:

komment_id = wpX.call(NewComment(post_id, komment))

I have tried a lot of options and non of them works:

Fail1:
wpnumber = randint(1,10)
test = str('wp')+str(wpnumber)
komment_id = test.call(NewComment(post_id, komment))

Fail2:
komment_id = %d.call(NewComment(post_id, komment)) % (test)

Fail3: (and all its mutation with " ' ( ) , ( )  ) etc.
komment_id = test + .call(NewComment(post_id, komment))

Fail4:
komment_id = wp+wpnumber+.call(NewComment(post_id, komment))

To be honest, I tried 10 different ways with %s with %d, joining variables, spliting everything...

Anyone Could Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using string concatenation. The `test` variable which you are using must have exactly the same type as `wp1` or `wp2`, which cannot be generated using string concatenation.

You can do it like this. Store the randint(1,10) in a number and check that number through all the options.

```
number = randint(1,10)
if (number == 1):
    test = wp1
elif (number == 2):
    test = wp2
```

This will ensure both, randomness and that your `test` variable is of the same type(`Client`) as `wp`.